# No login appearing, only drum sound and lowercase

Tags: boot, dual-boot, login, lightdm

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 for the first time on my new laptop, unfortunately, it has been nothing but a bit hassle.

When I booted the bootable USB with Ubuntu 18.04 it wouldn't install, so somebody suggested to install 16.04 first and upgrade from there. That was what I did, and that when my laptop kept hanging into the [bootup screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt8uF.jpg), but I was still able to access the tty. After looking around I was thinking it was GNOME that was acting up so I installed lightdm. I was quite happy when my I finally heard the drum start up sound and was expecting a login screen. Unfortunately all I got was a lowercase in the left-hand corner of my laptop. I am still able to get into my tty, so could anyone help me to finally get to my login screen.

My laptop is a dual boot with Windows 10, I do not know if this is relevant. Thank you.

Comment: 1st comment: "it wouldn't install" - it did not offer, or what? Honestly a clean install is always better than upgrade. 2nd comment: Did your X started? I mean it could be something related to graphics, but it is just hint.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently.  While in tty check to see what themes are installed:  "apt list --installed | grep themes."  Purge all themes not relevant.

Gnome should be using gdm, which is the Gnome Display Manager.  (See if it's installed and running.)